# Programmatically updating selected rows misses the last one in dgv.DataSource.GetChanges()?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data grid view with a column (combobox column). The following function has been implemented.

1. Select several rows (click the left most row header and drag).
2. Programmingly set the value to something (see following). All the selected rows changes.

   ```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgv.SelectedRows)
       {
           item.Cells["cbxxxxx"].Value = p;
       }
       dgv.EndEdit();
   ```
3. Click the save button to save the changes. However, the last row is excluded in the `(dgv.DataSource as DataTable).GetChanges()`. The count of the changed data table is always one less than the selected rows. The missing row is the last one (with the black triangle).

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to place the `EndEdit` call before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Just tried and changes data table still has one less row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last row presumably is still the active row, so you need to end the edit through the BindingContext:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgv.SelectedRows) {
  item.Cells["cbxxxxx"].Value = p;
}
this.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
```

Comment: Why `dgv.EndEdit()` doesn't work? The method name hints it too.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Not 100% sure of the reason, but the grid has the last row marked as the active one, so it isn't necessarily in edit mode, so nothing to end.  The BindingContext is treating it a little differently.