# Updating DataGridView Selected Rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows, selected

I tried to update selected rows in DataGridView, but the result is strange, it always missing a row or another. The problem is when I click btnSettled button to set the settled date, then click btnUpdate to update the database, the result seems ok, but after click btnRefresh to refresh the DGV, there is always a missing row. Is that the problem on UpdateCommand or foreach loop? Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

before click btnSettle
[image: before click btnSettled]

after click btnSettled and btnUpdate
[image: after click btnSettled and btnUpdate]

after click btnRefresh
[image: after click btnRefresh]

My code as follows:

```
DataTable dtTrx = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter daTrx = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dsTrx = new DataSet();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getData();
    }

    private void getData()
    {
        string strConn = "Data Source=.\\xpw;Initial Catalog=MyStock;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();

        string sqlTrx = "SELECT TrxID, TrxDate,Ticker,Qty,Price,Type,AccID, SettledDate,BrokerUserID FROM Trx";

        daTrx = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlTrx, conn);
        SqlCommandBuilder cbTrx = new SqlCommandBuilder(daTrx);
        daTrx.Fill(dsTrx, "trx");

        conn.Close();

        dtTrx = dsTrx.Tables["trx"];
        dgvTrx.DataSource = dtTrx;
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        daTrx.Update(dsTrx, "trx");
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dsTrx.Clear();
        daTrx.Fill(dsTrx, "trx");
    }

    private void btnSettled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgvTrx.SelectedCells)
        {
            dgvTrx[7, c.RowIndex].Value = "2017/7/23";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: If I edit SettledDate manually on DGV, then click Update and Refresh, the result is ok.

Comment: It would be better to loop like `foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTrx.SelectedRows)` then apply the value by using  `r.Cells["SettledDate"].Value = "2017/7/23";`

Comment: The getData() should be triggered after the foreach loop in order to update the gridview so to speach

Comment: @Nobody, I've just tried your suggestion, the result is just the same, missing a row. thanks.

Comment: @xpw have u tried the answer i posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need start using parameterized SQL queries.

Secondly I don't see a problem with your code, but you try this :

```
private void btnSettled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTrx.SelectedRows)
    {
        r.Cells["SettledDate"].Value = "2017/7/23"; //use the column name instead of column index
    }
    this.BindingContext[dgvTrx.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit(); 
    //the above line is added to improve the solution
    //as per the link mentioned in the accepted answer
}
```

The reason behind this approach is that now even if you change the column position, you won't have to re-write the code to match the changes

As you are using `SelectedCells`, thus unless your mouse is dragged over to the last `Cell` it won't be added in the `SelectedCell` collection

Note: in `r.Cells["SettledDate"].Value` I assumed the column name is `SettledDate`

Comment: yes, your way is more elegant to maintain the code. but unfortunately the result is the same - missing a row. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that but I tested my code snippet now and is working for me. anyways lemme look at your code again

Comment: The selected rows are all highlighted, I think it clearly indicates which rows are selected.

Comment: Is that any problem with the underlying database table, but I think the table is quite simple.

Comment: I don't think the table is the culprit here. Although I'm still baffled that this is working for me all the way, but not for you :/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution in :

[Programmingly udpating selected rows misses the last one in dgv.DataSource.GetChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26556615/6611487)

It only needs to end-edit the last row after foreach loop:

```
this.BindingContext[dgvTrx.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
```

Thanks again to @Nobody.

Comment: Great you found the solution! I've also updated my solution to mark the changes. Also thanks to you, i learned something today ;]